# Ways to display links to pages on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, links

I currently have 15 pages on a site collection and am looking for an out of the box solution for visual purposes.

As of now there are 15 quick links with a SharePoint page icon next to them. They are used for a reference guide so they are all categories that should be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

As you want SharePoint out of the box solution, you can continue using Quick Links web part. However to make it more appealing visually, you can consider using different layout options available in Quick links web part:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use the Quick Links web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82)

**Examples**:

1. Quick Links - Button layout:

[image]

2. Quick Links - Grid layout:

[image]

You can try different layouts available and use the one which suits best for your SharePoint site & page where you have added these links.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the design of links, you can also use the SharePoint list to store information related to site pages (page name, link, etc.) and use JSON formatting to customize the display of links.

Then add "List" web part on home page (where you want to show the links) and show the JSON formatted customized list on the page.

This given you better flexibility over the design and you can manage (add/remove/hide based on flag column) the page links from SharePoint list without editing the home page.

Check below samples which should help you with this:

1. [Honeycomb Links](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/honeycomb-link)

   [image]
2. [Icon Link Tiles](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/icon-link-tiles)

   [image]